# How to wait until a web page is redirected after clicking a button of another web page in codeception?

Tags: php, selenium-webdriver, codeception, webautomation

```
/**
 * @param int $timeout : timeout period
 * @throws ModuleException
 */
public function waitAjaxLoad($timeout = 10)
{
    $this->webDriverModule->waitForJS('return !!window.jQuery && window.jQuery.active == 0;', $timeout);
    $this->webDriverModule->wait(1);
    $this->dontSeeJsError();
}

/**
 * @param int $timeout : timeout period
 * @throws ModuleException
 */
public function waitPageLoad($timeout = 10)
{
    $this->webDriverModule->waitForJs('return document.readyState == "complete"', $timeout);
    $this->waitAjaxLoad($timeout);
    $this->dontSeeJsError();
}
```

> These two functions did not work for me. Are there any workaround to
>   wait until the redirected page is loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before invoking these methods,

```
/**
 * @param int $timeout : timeout period
 * @throws ModuleException
 */
public function waitAjaxLoad($timeout = 10)
{
    $this->webDriverModule->waitForJS('return !!window.jQuery && window.jQuery.active == 0;', $timeout);
    $this->webDriverModule->wait(1);
    $this->dontSeeJsError();
}

/**
 * @param int $timeout : timeout period
 * @throws ModuleException
 */
public function waitPageLoad($timeout = 10)
{
    $this->webDriverModule->waitForJs('return document.readyState == "complete"', $timeout);
    $this->waitAjaxLoad($timeout);
    $this->dontSeeJsError();
}
```

I had to invoke `$this->switchToNextTab(1);` to move to the next tab in the browser.

Once your test case clicks on the submit button and it routes to a different page with a new browser tab, then you have to switchToNextTab by invoking `$this->switchToNextTab(1);`.
After moving to the next-tab you can wait for the new page is to be loaded.

Comment: Senal, the other answer is a lot more generally useful FWIW, if you're not sure, I'd suggest you change the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Most stable solution I found:

```
    $I->waitForJS('return document.oldPage = "yes"');
    $I->submitForm('form', ['field1' => 'xyz']);
    $I->waitForJS('return document.oldPage !== "yes"');
```

Because it when i trigger submitForm it doesn't wait for the page to load, and the page is still active for a short period until it starts to load, and once it starts to load the JS stops to evaluate and start once it's loaded.

Comment: Holy moly this works! I've been waiting years for a solution to this other than desperately trying to find something on the second page that's not on the first to ->see() (e.g. "Settings updated").

Comment: I added these as helper methods on the tester class, so useful! This should 100% be part of Codeception, we can't be the only ones who need this constantly!?!? https://gist.github.com/jerclarke/c5328ed59571a88342034e15c90a3c33

Comment: I love how simple and common sense this is. Nothing fancy, does exactly what it seems it will. The only downside is having to run it before and after, but it's a simple, repeatable pattern.

Comment: @jerclarke

you could wrap `submitForm` in a helper like `submitFormAndWaitForPageChange` that would do those 3 lines :)

Answer (score -2):

What are you trying to do? These functions seem overly complex. Are you trying to check for errors or check for the expected page? I'd try to do one or the other. Do you know the expected result of the next page? Could you just do this:

```
sleep(10);
$I->see('something on the expected page');
```

In any case, I looked at your code, and within 10 seconds I couldn't figure out what it's trying to do. Which to me means you need to re-factor or something.

Comment: I found the issue. Before invoking these methods I had to invoke $this->switchToNextTab(1); function to move to the next tab. Because after clicking submit it routes to another site by opening a new tab in the browser.